# C++ fstream - Account login/registration via txt file

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I'm new to c++ and trying to create an account manager to handle:
log, register, change pass, etc.

I'm having difficulties with comparing user input for username and password:

EDIT:
My problem is that getline(openFile, tempUser, ';'); doesnt go to the next line after semi-colon.

So if I have USERNAME;PASSWORD, it checks username and password as if they are account names.

This is my LOGIN function:

```
void AccountManager::login(AccountManager &account){
  string username, password, tempUser, tempPass;
  int wrongUser(0);
  fstream openFile("UserPass.txt", ios::out | ios::in | ios::app);
  if(openFile.good()){
    do{
      cout << "Type in your username: " << endl;
      getline(cin, username);
      cin.sync();
      cout << "Type in your password: " << endl;
      getline(cin, password);
      cin.sync();
      while(!openFile.eof()){
        getline(openFile, tempUser, ';');
        if(tempUser == username){
          getline(openFile.ignore(tempUser.length()+1),tempPass);
          if(tempPass == password){
            wrongUser = 1;
            cout << "Thank you for logging in. " << endl;
            switchLog(account);
          }else{
            cout << "Wrong username or password, please try again." << endl; ;
            break;
          }
        }
      };
    }while(wrongUser = 0); // <<< while loop not working
  }
  else{ //cant Open file - error handling
    if( account.UserPass[username] == password){
      switchLog(account);
    }
    else{
      cout << "The username and password do not match. ";
    }
    cerr << "Error accessing data!" <<endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  openFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the file is formatted as so: USERNAME;PASSWORD

Comment: Is this for a system with real security requirements, or just a homework exercise where security doesn't actually matter?

Comment: What exactly are the difficulties that you're having?

Comment: `getline(openFile, tempUser, ';');` is one problem. You read part of the line but don't skip over the rest of it when the user name doesn't match.

Comment: This is a hw assignment guys, @CaptainObvlious , how do I skip the rest im really new to fstream. jwodder its as captain stated, I check USERNAME; and want it to go to next line at semi-colon, instead it continues to check the PASSWORD after the semi-colon as if its a USERNAME.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious but wouldnt my while loop keep recalling that function anyways till its an end of file?

Comment: Yes. but if you read in the username and don't skip the password the next time you try to load the username you actually get the password that hasn't been skipped **and** the next username since your use of a delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If checking the username fails you still have extra data on that line that hasn't been read in yet. Consider if the input data was the following

```
username1;password
username2;password
```

When you read the first line and the username does not match you have `password` *dangling* on the current input line. So now your input looks like this

```
password
username2;password
```

The next time you read in the username you get `password username` where the space is a non-printable line ending. This will continue until you read the entire file so only the first username and password pair in the file can ever be found.

To fix this you can use `std::getline` to skip the remaining text on the input line.

```
if(tempUser == username)
{
    // valid username. Read the password
}
else
{ 
    // skip rest of the line
    getline(openFile, tempUser);
}
```

Or read both values at the same time and simplify your logic

```
getline(openFile, tempUser, ';');
getline(openFile, tempPassword);

if(tempUser == username)
{
}
```

Comment: So by calling getline in this fashion, It automatically loads the data after the delimiter correct? so have it in a while loop till EOF, including both getlines.

Comment: Everything except the _automatic_ part is correct yet. You're doing it yourself so it's manually ;)

Comment: Hey, This has been my fix, it works great ty.       while(!openFile.eof()){
        getline(openFile, tempUser, ';');
        getline(openFile, tempPass);
        if((tempUser == username)&&(tempPass == password)){